# Getting class is frozen Runtime Exception while invoking webservice call and port-type

Tags: exception, runtime, javassist

We are trying to make a soap webservice call when we are getting the below Runtime exception continously. we are running on AJSC7 platform. 
Ecception is coming from  "org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create"
`iLib: ILIB-MSG-009 Something went wrong in the transformer.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.att.csi.csi.namespaces.customercareprofile.types._public.commondatamodel.DiscountInfo$JaxbAccessorF_description class is frozen
    at ilib.javassist.CtClassType.checkModify(CtClassType.java:309)
    at ilib.javassist.CtBehavior.getMethodInfo(CtBehavior.java:111)
    at com.att.ilib.transformer.InstrumentMeTransformer.getAnnotation(InstrumentMeTransformer.java:82)
    at com.att.ilib.transformer.InstrumentMeTransformer.transform(InstrumentMeTransformer.java:62)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:271)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:87)`

Answer (score 2):

use isFrozen( ) method to check if it is acutally frozen and deFrost it for further modification. Javassist freezes a class when it is loaded so that further changes will be prohibited.
check out the following links for further reference.

[official javassist tuorial for frozen class](https://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

[samples for deFrost( )](http://massapi.com/method/javassist/CtClass.defrost.html)